# My own Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Please i need some one to help me out on this, i want to replace character like Dr, Rd and St with Drive Road and Street, using regular expression, please how can this be done? I have tried so many ways but my result is nt right.
for example if the user supply this address for the variable vaddress: 
13, Clinton str off allen rd queens dr.
The result should be
13, Clinton street off allen road queens drive.

here is a sample of my code:

```
    public void standardizeAddress(String vaddress){
        address = vaddress;//address is an instance variable
        String str1,str2;
       //Replace all instances of 'St,Rd,Dr' with 'Street,Road and Drive' Using

            String regex = "\\sSt\\s";
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher match = pat.matcher(address);
            while(match.find())
             address = match.replaceAll(" Street ");
             System.out.println(address);
             str1 = address;

            regex = "\\sRd\\s";
            pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
            match = pat.matcher(str1);
            while(match.find())
            str1 = match.replaceAll(" Road ");
            System.out.println(str1);
            str2 = str1;

            regex = "\\sDr\\s";
            pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
            match = pat.matcher(str2);
            while(match.find())
            str2 = match.replaceAll(" Drive ");
            System.out.println(str2);    
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the input? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: Would using [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) not be enough?

Comment: Such a complicated code for such an easy job. Use `yourString.replaceAll(" St ", " Street ")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
String str = "Dr abc Rd def St ghi";
str = str.replaceAll("(\\s+|^)Dr(\\s+|$)", "$1Drive$2");
str = str.replaceAll("(\\s+|^)Rd(\\s+|$)", "$1Road$2");
str = str.replaceAll("(\\s+|^)St(\\s+|$)", "$1Street$2");

System.out.println(str);
```

An yield:

> Drive abc Road def Street ghi

This code should maintain the spaces as well prior to the words you would like to replace.

Comment: You also need to consider any other punctuation that can come after `Dr` or `Rd`. Of course that is not mentioned in the current question. So, probably this should be left to OP to manipulate the regex. Else this is all fine. +1

Comment: `(\\s+|^)Dr(\\s+|$)` can also be replaced with `\\bDr\\b`. And then just replace with `Drive`.

Comment: @RohitJain: Although I do agree with what you are saying, I am lacking context for this problem. What if I have an address like so: Dr. Foo Barr, foo1Dr foo2Rd foo3St. In this case, `Dr.` stands for Doctor.

Comment: @npinti.. Yeah exactly. And that is why I said, it should be left to OP to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I think if your situation is really simple and your scenario is small (and you don't need complicated regexps), you can simply use [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Matcher the following code example will help you :)

```
String address = "St number 9 and St number 99 and st number 999";       
String regex = "\\bSt\\b";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher match = pat.matcher(address);
address = match.replaceAll("Street");
System.out.println(address);
```

Results in output: `Street number 9 and Street number 99 and st number 999`

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the usage of Pattern and Matcher. I think the simple answer with several replaceAll is most readable.

```
    Map<String, String> replacements = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // Keep in order
    replacements.put("Dr", "Drive");
    replacements.put("Rd", "Road");
    replacements.put("St", "Street");

    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
    for (String abbrev : replacements.keySet()) {
        regex.append(regex.length() == 0? "\\b(" : "|");
        regex.append(Pattern.quote(abbrev));
    }
    regex.append(")\\b");
    Pattern abbrevPattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());
    Matcher m = abbrevPattern.matcher(vaddress);

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String outwritten = replacements.get(m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(result, outwritten);
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
    return result.toString();
```